# Parsing POST body using Wai and Warp

Tags: haskell, web

I am trying to use Wai and Warp to write a modest HTTP server and I am stuck trying to read POST/PUT request's bodies to extract form parameters. When I do the following

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import Network.Wai.Parse (parseRequestBody, lbsSink)
import Network.Wai(Response(..))
import Network.HTTP.Types(status200)
import Blaze.ByteString.Builder

main = run 3000 app

app req = do
  (params, _) <- parseRequestBody lbsSink req
  let r = C.concat $ map (\(x,y) -> C.concat [x,y]) params
  return $ ResponseBuilder 
      status200
      [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
      $ fromByteString r
```

and then I try a simple request like

```
curl -o - -X POST http://localhost:3000/ -d  name=toto
```

it appears my parameters don't get passed to other server, or rather do not get decoded properly as nothing is returned.

Comment: I just tried your code on the latest versions of `warp`, `wai` and `wai-extra`, and it prints `nametoto` as expected. Note that it does _not_ print a newline, so perhaps your shell is overwriting it with the prompt? Try piping the result to a file to check if this is the case.

Comment: OK. Definitely need more sleep and forbid myself posting questions after 10pm ! Thanks for pointing me at this.